# Capturing Vagrant Network Traffic

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, vagrant

I've got a VM running.  I use HTTP Scoop for debugging Ajax requests, but unfortunately, with bridged networking and a static IP, I cannot see network activity to my VM.

Is there a configuration change I need to make?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vagrant is wrapper around VirtualBox. You can use [package capture](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Network_tips) and analyse it in Wireshark.

> Network tracing Network problems could be detected by enabling packet  logging at the guest side or at the host side, but using the built-in capability of VirtualBox to create pcap files might provide even more useful information because it contains a log of really all packets received and sent by guest.
>
> To enable network tracing do the following: 
>   VBoxManage modifyvm [your-vm] --nictrace[adapter-number] on --nictracefile[adapter-number] file.pcap 
>   For example 
>   VBoxManage modifyvm "ubuntu" --nictrace1 on --nictracefile1 trace1.pcap

If you use vagrant add following lines to `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictrace1", "on"]
config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictracefile1", "trace1.pcap"]
```

Then open `trace1.pcap` file in Wireshark.

Comment: With new versions of vagrant the code would look like:
`config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |v|  
    v.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--nictrace1', 'on']  
    v.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--nictracefile1', 'trace1.pcap']  
end`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am completely mistaken, you should be able to use wireshark to capture traffic between the two VM's.  You may have to configure wireshark properly - you may wish to check bridged or host only traffic options.

Comment: Tried to listen on just the IP, tried all network interfaces.  The VM is bridged to en1, but even with a raw tcpdump I see nothing on en1.

Comment: wondering - the interface that you are using - is it configured for promiscuous mode via vagrant

Comment: curious - were you able to figure it out